# Python post request returning unexpected result all of the sudden

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I ran my inventory-watching webscraper overnight, and all of the sudden, I started getting errors and I checked what the inventory post request was returning and it's this:

```
{"sec-cp-challenge": "true","provider":"crypto","branding_url_content":"/_sec/cp_challenge/crypto_message-2-9.htm","chlg_duration":7}
```

It's supposed to be a bunch of inventory data, but all of a sudden I'm getting this result. I'm not sure if it's because they've changed something, or if they've banned me or something, but when I go to the inventory source in the F12 menu, everything looks all good.

Here's the store page: https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/herters-hunting-rifle-ammo
and here's the inventory stock page: https://www.basspro.com/shop/BPSGetOnlineInventoryStatusByIDView

If anybody knows why I'm getting that weird crypto-related snippet, I would be indebted to you if you helped me out! I have a suspicion that they added a little waiting page that I'm getting rather than the inventory page that I want.

here's my code:

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
'From': 'uadpjones@gmail.com',
}

store_url = 'https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/herters-target-handgun-ammo'
stock_url = 'https://www.basspro.com/shop/BPSGetOnlineInventoryStatusByIDView'

productId = 3074457345619161625
storeId = 715838534
catalogId = 3074457345616676768

while True:
    try:
        stock_page = requests.post(stock_url, headers=headers,
                                   data={'productId': productId, 'storeId': storeId, 'catalogId': catalogId}).text
        ammo_status = re.search(r'\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t"status": "((In|Out of) Stock)"',
                                stock_page, flags=re.S).group(1)
        print('(9mm) {}'.format(ammo_status))
        break
    except:
        print('Error: exception triggered (9mm)')
        print(stock_page)
        time.sleep(10)
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is akamai's bot_chanllege_html.
The branding_url_content is the url of bot_chanllege_html.
This html while send sensor_data to the server.Then update cookies.So the server while besure you are not a bot.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, try updating the headers to include

referrer = URL

In your case this would be store_url